# How do I force "bundle install" to use the installed version of Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, rvm, bundler

I just re-installed Ruby 2.4.0 ...

```
myuser@myproject:~$ sudo env "PATH=$PATH" rvm reinstall ruby-2.4.0
ruby-2.4.0 - #removing rubies/ruby-2.4.0..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rubies.travis-ci.org/ubuntu/14.04/x86_64/ruby-2.4.0.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
ruby-2.4.0 - #configure
ruby-2.4.0 - #download
ruby-2.4.0 - #validate archive
ruby-2.4.0 - #extract
ruby-2.4.0 - #validate binary
ruby-2.4.0 - #setup
ruby-2.4.0 - #gemset created /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global
ruby-2.4.0 - #importing gemset /usr/local/rvm/gemsets/global.gems...................................
ruby-2.4.0 - #generating global wrappers........
ruby-2.4.0 - #gemset created /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0
ruby-2.4.0 - #importing gemsetfile /usr/local/rvm/gemsets/default.gems evaluated to empty gem list
ruby-2.4.0 - #generating default wrappers........
Making gemset ruby-2.4.0 pristine.................................................................
Making gemset ruby-2.4.0@global pristine.................................................................
```

However, despite the fact I'm seeing the right version returned by "ruby -v", my "bundle install" seems to be pointed at an older version of Ruby ...

```
rails@myproject:~$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-linux]
rails@myproject:~$ cd myproject
rails@myproject:~/myproject$ bundle install
-su: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/bundle: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

HOw do I force bundle to point at the right version of Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bundle fails because you don't have installed bundler in the 2.4.0 rvm gemset. To fix that, you should do this in your current version of ruby:

```
gem install bundler
bundle
```

Make sure that your Ruby version is the same as declared on `Gemfile`.

Comment: are you sure that's the case. look at his error message: `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/bundle: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`. looks like the bundler being executed *is* the gem for 2.4.0.

Comment: actually, upon further research, it looks like you're probably right. but why does the error message seem to imply that bundle is already installed for 2.4.0?

Comment: It's not implied. The error just says that bundler expect to find an ruby executable on the same version that you're working. However, the PATH returns another ruby executable where bundler is not installed.